# Converting emoji to HTML Decimal Code or Unicode Hexadecimal Code in java

Tags: java, html, html-entities, emoji, html-encode

I am trying to convert text file with emoji content to the file with emoji's html code or Hex code using Java.
example :

I/p : `&lt;div id="thread" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"&gt;&lt;div&gt;⚽️`

Expected o/p :`&lt;div id="thread" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"&gt;&lt;div&gt;&#128512;&#128512;&#128515;&#127822;&#127823;&#9917;&#65039;&#127936;`

In above out put `''` should get changed to the corresponding html entity code`'& # 128512;'`

Detail of Html entity code and hex code is given here :
http://character-code.com/emoticons-html-codes.php

Sample code that i tried is below :

```
try {
            File file = new File("/inFile.txt");
            str = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "ISO-8859-1");
            System.out.println(new String(str.getBytes(), "UTF-8"));
            String results = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(str);
            System.out.println(results);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: So you have code to do something, you don't show us the code, and then ask why the code doesn't work? *Really?!?!?*

Comment: added sample code that i tried.

Comment: Are you sure the file uses `ISO-8859-1` encoding? That seems... unlikely.

Comment: i am not sure on that.. we are getting xml file with  encoding="UTF-8".These emoji characters are part of the CDATA.I am just trying to decode and convert with corresponding  HTML entity code for the emoji.

Comment: So you problem seems to center on `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4()`, and your complaint is that is doesn't map emoji's correctly. 1) I assume that's from Apache Commons Lang? 2) What version of that library are you using? 3) Why are you even trying to do this, rather than just writing HTML in UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

```
I got the work around :
public static void htmlDecimalCodeGenerator () {

  DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

  domFactory.setValidating(false);

   // File inputFile = new File("/inputFile.xml");
   File inputFile = new File("/inputFile.xml");



   try {

  FileOutputStream fop = null;

  File OutFile = new File("/outputFile.xml");

  fop = new FileOutputStream(OutFile);



  DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

  Document doc = builder.parse(inputFile);



  TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

  Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();



   /*
  no value of OMIT_XML_DECLARATION will add following xml declaration in the beginning of the file.
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-32'?>
  */
   transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");



   /*

  When the output method is "xml", the version value specifies the
  version of XML to be used for outputting the result tree. The default
  value for the xml output method is 1.0. When the output method is
  "html", the version value indicates the version of the HTML.
  The default value for the xml output method is 4.0, which specifies
  that the result should be output as HTML conforming to the HTML 4.0
  Recommendation [HTML]. If the output method is "text", the version
  property is ignored
  */
   transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");



   /*
  Indent-- specifies whether the Transformer may
  add additional whitespace when outputting the result tree; the value
  must be yes or no.
  */
   transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");





  transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");

   // transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

   transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc),

   new StreamResult(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "UTF-8")));

   // new StreamResult(new OutputStreamWriter(fop, "UTF-8")));


   } catch (Exception e) {

  e.printStackTrace();

  }

}

}
```